# OPTAPLANNER: Pre-define value of planning variable

Tags: optimization, constraints, optaplanner

I would like to know if it is possible to pre-fix the value of some of the planning variables in the planning entity so that they cannot change during the optimization (i.e. fix that a specific job will be scheduled on a particular day).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pin the entire planning entity so that OptaPlanner does not change the planning variable assignments there.

Please see the [pinned Planning Entities documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#pinnedPlanningEntities).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is very helpful. However, I can't find how to pin only the value of one of the planning variables of the planning entity, instead of the whole entity. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: It's an open issue. Currently not supported. There's a jira for it, but it's non-trivial to implement, especially in the current move selector architecture.